# How to reference a static file in Django that isn't inside my static file directory?

Tags: javascript, django, django-tinymce

I want to use a javascript file that isn't in my static URL nor in any file that would be collected when running collect static. How would a point to this file in a way that I don't have to use {% load static %}

It is basically so I can have only my DjangoTiny-MCE files in my Heroku server without collecting static instead of storing them in AWS because that has proven troublesome.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It's fine to host your static files on Heroku - it's even fully described in the Heroku docs for Django, including how to configure Whitenoise to serve them. It's only user-uploaded media files that you mustn't safe on the Heroku filesystem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already have my static files in AWS and I want to keep them there, but I want only the static files related to TinyMCE to be Heroku so that I stop getting errors that occur on about those files being on a different domain (Same-origin policy).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you know if it's possible to use some static files from AWS and others from Heroku using whitenoise? That would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to host your file on some server if you have otherwise there are many free options available then use that file as **CDN** in your template just like other JS file links.